# Big gaps in GTmetrix waterfall chart, is there a way to get rid of them?

Tags: performance, web, lazy-loading, waterfall, gtmetrix

I managed to build a decently optimized website, but I keep seeing this huge gap in the waterfall chart that adds like ~300 ms to my loading time. This happens right before ajax get_refreshed_fragments starts loading (that's the big one loading there) and the next 5 elements are just some lazy-loaded images.

Is there something I can do about this, maybe force it to load faster? I don't want to disable it, it is a good addition to my site and makes the user experience better, but I see no reason that gap should be there. Here is a screenshot:

[Waterfall Chart Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbn7o.png)

Any suggestions or opinions would be much appreciated.

Thanks